# wine and nvidia optimus problem

Tags: wine, games, nvidia-optimus

I have Asus N53SN computer which has nvidia optimus. Rift online is working on my ubuntu but its using intel card. i need to make it work with geforce.
But optirun wine riftpatcher.exe saying to me ;

wine: cannot find L"C:\windows\system32\riftpatchlive.exe"

so how can i make it work with geforce? 
and one more thing since rift has launcher and client separately ,is geforce going to work with client too?

im new to ubuntu .. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are not specifying the correct path for your application. Rift online is most likely not installed in your system32 folder (where is where wine will search by default if no absolute path is specified).

Check where it is installed on your virtual hard drive (C:) and type in that path

For Example:

```
optirun wine "C:\program files\riftpatch\riftpatchlive.exe"
```

Also if you are using bumblebee, i would suggest you install also primusrun (it is included with the same ppa you installed bumblebee with). Primusrun gives much better performance than using the optirun command and often solves problems that would be present using optirun.

```
sudo apt-get install primus
```

Then run the command with primusrun.

```
primusrun wine "C:\program files\riftpatch\riftpatchlive.exe"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll be honest, I tried primusrun but the performance is terrible compared to optirun. I get 65fps if I use primusrun on glxspheres and I get 178fps using optirun.. Anyway each to their own as the Optimus technology is still evolving.. Don't forget to export the GLX libraries when using optirun

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/nvidia-325:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

(Note that the nvidia-325 is the driver i currently have installed, depending on what version of the nvidia driver your entry above will look a little different)

Comment: Primusrun normally has vsync enabled. Try running `vblank_mode=0 primusrun glxspheres` and it should outperform optirun.