# How to choose dedicated videocard over integrated videocard in a laptop?

Tags: nvidia, intel-graphics, lenovo, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I have a `Lenovo z580 laptop` and it has 2 video cards

- Intel HD Graphics 2000 integrated in Intel Pentium Dual Core CPU B970
- nVidia Geforce GT 630M.

I use `Bumblebee` but it doesn't work for Virtual Box ghost OS or for Wine. How I can `remove/eliminate` the integrated video card and use only **nVidia Geforce GT 630M**?

Comment: if this is an true optimus configuration the nvidia card is probably only for acceleration and lacks the components to run standalone. You available BIOS options suggest this is the case on your laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, in nvidia-optimus the intel card is connected to display & images processed by nvidia card is passed through intel card.  so you can't disable it.

However start looking in BIOS , some model (very rare) gives option for disabling intel card. Even I heard about hidden menu in BIOS for one particular model.

Second chance is, if your hdmi port is wired to nvidia card. You can connect an external display and run apps on that. your laptop display will be disabled in such case. you will get full instruction on bumblee official faq page.

if the above two are not available to you, I fear you are out of luck.

As per my knowledge, wine does run using optimus. See [wine and nvidia optimus problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/338015/wine-and-nvidia-optimus-problem)

There are two aspect of virtual box running under dedicated card, I don't know which one  you are talking, I will clarify

1. Virtual box guest (you meant guest not ghost, I think) OS can never see your actual hardware. All hardware are emulated. It just relay on virtual box to interpret. So in virtual box OS, nvidia, intel whatever you have in actual, will be never be shown.
2. Running virtualbox (not the guest OS) itself using nvidia card for better 3D capability. There have been some work, but performance is not considerable.

Few more references:

[Enable graphics card in VirtualBox](https://askubuntu.com/q/139320/35775)

[How to use NVIDIA GeForce M310 on Ubuntu 12.10 running as guest in VirtualBox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202926/how-to-use-nvidia-geforce-m310-on-ubuntu-12-10-running-as-guest-in-virtualbox)

[IronHide / BumbleBee with a VirtualBox VM. Will it pass through video acceleration to the physical card?](https://askubuntu.com/q/82576/35775)

Regarding Photoshop CS6 in wine : See
https://askubuntu.com/a/348280/35775

Comment: in BIOS is option to change video mode: Only Intel or Intel + nVidia. Only nVidia option doesn't exist.

Comment: My laptop has HDMI port but I have not the second screen.

Comment: in Windows exist a devices manager, with it I can disassemble one or more devices, it make a list like it: ![screen](http://iceimg.com/crGN-ADr/screenshot-from-2013-11-06-214607.png)

Comment: If you disable intel card in windows device manager, the laptop display will be turned off immediately. You will have no choice except to reboot to make it working again.  It is by [design of optimus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nvidia_Optimus). Intel card is bridge between nvidia card and display. You can't disable it.

Comment: If I can't disable intel card and I can't use nVidia for wine and virtual box ghosts os, this problem have not solution...

Comment: I think wine can be run using optimus. As per this link [wine and nvidia optimus problem](http://askubuntu.com/q/338015) And secondly virtualbox can't use nvidia card even on windows.. A virtual box os can never see your actual hardware. All hardware are emulated that is why need to install guest addons.

Comment: See reference links for in updated answer.

Comment: It can work for games, but doesn't for adobe photoshop `err:module:attach_process_dlls "msvcp90.dll" failed to initialize, aborting
err:module:LdrInitializeThunk Main exe initialization for L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Adobe\\Adobe Photoshop CS6\\Photoshop.exe" failed, status c0000005`

Comment: Did you followed all as told here - [How to install photoshop cs6?](http://askubuntu.com/a/348280/35775) ?

Comment: I will try this method after, my ps work fine with intel video card but not work if I use optirun.

Comment: I will try to fix it after I will reply.